# New UI SiteEdit Implementation

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, experience-manager

I have implemented New UI SiteEdit in Tridion 2011 SP1. When I have created a page without components in it ,I  am able to edit the page. If I am inserting the component I am not able to edit the page. Please help on this issue?

Comment: Please do provide more detail like you final HTML before or after inserting CP, and explain what you mean by not able to edit?

Comment: Removed the c#, java and visual-studio tags on this question as they appear not relevant, added tridion-2011 and experience-manager. Plus I second the request for more detail like the final HTML as without it, this is impossible to answer.

Comment: If this is an admin/setup issue, maybe Webmaster Exchange would be a better place to ask. If this is from the user's perspective, maybe Super User.

Answer (score 2):

When changing a Page in New UI (Experience Manager or XPM), the page is checked-out. What you might be seeing for other users is expected behavior--other users should not be able to edit the page in the CME or within XPM.

Also, you should be restricted from editing content page for even the same user that has a *different session* (e.g. viewing the page from another browser).

When editing the page with the same user and session, you should be able to add multiple components. The page is checked out. Editing content on the page should be "editing components," rather than the page itself.

Let us know if you're seeing something else.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a result of having an syntax error in your inline editing commands (i.e. the JSON syntax inside HTML comments).  Normally you would use the OOTB building blocks that generate this for you, however, in some extreme scenarios, this syntax is written out by hand.  I suspect that you may have the latter scenario.  Verify your component and component field command syntax.

Comment: I see manually crafted Experience Manager JSON syntax in situations that have a "rendering framework" and some intermediate (non-HTML) format for Component Presentations.